# Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

Tags: xamarin.forms

everyone, I face the following error in Xamarin, any idea to solve this error?

```
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which package added you recently?
I had this problem with Xam.Media.Plugin package, if I use 2.6.0 instead of 3.1.3